# How can I get full width on sidebar, while keeping right column on the right?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I just want to float everything on the right. Problem is that second right div is always at the bottom of left div, and if I put height 100% on the left div, then mobile versions suck.

Here is my code and css. I want to keep menu on the left, and nothing below, and on the right this 'cards' that are floated right.

```
<div class="feed-wrapper">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="col-md-3">
            <div class="feed-left">
                <ul>
                    <li>Laracasts</li>
                    <li>Modern web</li>
                    <li>Css daily</li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
        @foreach($feeds as $feed)
            <div class="col-md-9">
                <div class="feed-card">
                    <div class="feed-card-left" style="background-image: url({{ $feed->image }})">
                        {{-- <img src="{{ $feed->image}}"> --}}
                    </div>
                    <div class="feed-card-right" >
                        <h3>{{ $feed->title }}</h3>
                        <p>{{ str_limit($feed->description, 100) }}</p>
                        <hr>
                        {{ $feed->resource }}
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        @endforeach
    </div>
</div>
```

And CSS

```
.feed-wrapper {
    background: #EEF2F3;
}

.feed-left {
    margin: 20px 0;
    border-radius: 10px;
    background: white;
    display: flex;
}

.feed-left {
    padding: 10px;
}
.feed-left ul {
    list-style-type: none;
}

.feed-card {
    background: white;
    margin: 20px 0px;
    display: flex;
    border-radius: 5px;
}

.feed-card-left  {
    width: 25%;
    background-position: center;
    background-size: 350px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    border-top-left-radius: 5px;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 5px;
}

.feed-card-right {
    margin-left: 15px;
    float: right;
}
```

[image: Working project]

Answer (score 0):

Maybe put the sidebar in a containing div that is display:flex;

Comment: Or all of the right-aligned content in a container div that is only 80% width or whatever of the screen, and float right.

Comment: You mean class 'sidebar'?